# mongodb: inserting and querying geometries and WMS

Tags: mongodb, gis, geoserver

I am discovering mongodb, looks nice but i am still wondering if it can solve my needs.
The question is that we have 16 million point data and we want to cross some part of it with polygons to get statistics (how many points in each polygon).

Basic geometries would be cell degrees (1 degree, 0.5 degree...) covering all the world. In that case the $within function would work, right?

But I wonder, how do I insert these geometries (coming from a shapefile)  inside mongodb? Till now I was using postgreSQL-postGIS, and for that I have a lot of tools, but for mongodb...I am also wondering if more complex geometries could be inserted and queried against points.

MongoDB only provides JSON as result, right? if we want to plot some hundreds of points it would be no problem, but hundreds of thousands to be converted to vectorial data via javascript... is for this reason that WMS services are useful, as they provide one image.

Any hope to connect mongodb to any WMS? I saw someone announcing a plugin for Geoserver but it makes a year ago and nothing happened since then.

In case it is not possible, about how many GeoJSON features can be plotted at time keeping a nice browser performance?

Comment: I don't think geoserver could be deployed into a mongoDB, mainly because it uses a lot of postgis functions, and postgis only run on postgreSQL, not even MySQL or Oracle can be used with postGIS. :(

Comment: @pacofvf geoserver does not depend on PostGIS, that is just one back end it can use. The others are listed [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not much help, but I saw [a talk on someone who added MongoDB as a back end to GeoServer](http://www.fosslc.org/drupal/content/integration-geoserver-nosql-databases) last year.

IIRC, he said he would open source it (if his company approved), so maybe it's worth tracking him down.

EDIT: Looks like he got approval. Dug up some code [here](http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geotools/gt-mongodb/8-SNAPSHOT/) but not sure where associated documentation is. The Geotools/opengeo mailing list is where I found that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also starting to investigate using NoSQL for geographic data.

There is an [article](http://www.paolocorti.net/2009/12/06/using-mongodb-to-store-geographic-data/)

The example code Python, PyMongo and the OGR libraries to convert shapefiles to a MongoDB collection and vice versa.